# How to get time and date picker for yii2 application

Tags: yii2

i'm developing a website using yii2 framework, and them i need to save up an event time and date into the database so i need date and time picker i got dosamigos Datepicker but them it only gives date without time, how can i get a date and time picker, thanks to all

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'date')->widget(
    DatePicker::className(), [
    // inline too, not bad
     'inline' => false, 
     // modify template for custom rendering
    //'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd H-m-s'
    ]
]);?>
```

using this widget i got only date in the format specified but no time

Comment: use https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker

Comment: @ jithin thanks this help, add this as answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use yii2-widget-datetimepicker https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker

```
use kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker;
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'dp_1',
    'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
    'value' => '2020-02-02 10:10:10',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd H-m-s'
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use kartik datetime picker as well :[Kartik date time picker read doc here](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker)

```
use kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker;

echo '<label>Start Date/Time</label>';
echo DateTimePicker::widget([
    'name' => 'datetime_10',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select operating time ...'],
    'convertFormat' => true,
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'format' => 'd-M-Y g:i A',
        'startDate' => '01-Mar-2014 12:00 AM',
        'todayHighlight' => true
    ]
]);
```