# Current date in datepicker fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a form where I remade the bootstrap datepicker a little by inserting my fields with inputs, everything works as it should.

Now these fields are always empty. Is it possible to make the current date always displayed in these fields when navigating to the page?

I would also like to change the format so that it was like `01 01 2022`.

```js
// Initialize datepicker
const dp = $("#month").datepicker({ 
    todayHighlight: true
});

// Show datepicker on <input> click  
$('.input-wrapper > input').on('click', (e) => dp.datepicker("show"));

// On date change
const y  = document.getElementById('year');
const m  = document.getElementById('month');
const d  = document.getElementById('day');

dp.on('changeDate',function(ev){
    const date = dp.datepicker('getDate');
    y.value = date.getFullYear();
    d.value = date.getDate();
    dp.datepicker('hide');
    m.value = date.getMonth() + 1;
})

dp.on('hide',function(ev){
    const date = dp.datepicker('getDate');
    m.value = date.getMonth() + 1;
})
```

```css
label {
      color: #808694;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      line-height: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
}


    
input {
      margin-right: 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: #F4F5F8;
      width: 50px;
}

.span-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
      }
      
span {
        
        color: #808694;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 16px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50px;
}

.main-content {
  min-height: 10vh;
}

.call-form-item-date {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="main-content">
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
</div>

<div class="contacts-call-form">
    <form class="js-form" action="{{ route('send-comment') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item-date">
                <label for="date">Select a date *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <div id="datepickerContainer"></div>
                    <input class="js-form-month" id="month" type="text" name="month">
                    <input class="js-form-day" id="day" type="text" name="day">
                    <input class="js-form-year" id="year" type="text" name="year">
                    <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" style="display: none">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="span-wrapper">
          <span for="month">Month</span>
          <span for="day">Day</span>
          <span for="year">Year</span>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Read [documentations](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker#settings) and check about _convertFormat_ setting.Try it and if you get some error post your new code by updating your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get time and date picker for yii2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016448/how-to-get-time-and-date-picker-for-yii2-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can initialize the datepicker with several options :

```
var defaultDate = new Date();

const dp = $("#month").datepicker({ 
    setDate: defaultDate,
    format:'mm dd yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

- **setDate**: to initialize date picker with a default date
- **format**: define format of date selected picker + you have the method `dp.datepicker('getFormattedDate')` that allow you to get date from date picker with the configurate format

```js
// Initialize datepicker
var defaultDate = new Date();

const dp = $("#month").datepicker({ 
    setDate: defaultDate,
    format:'mm dd yyyy',
    todayHighlight: true
});

// Show datepicker on <input> click  
$('.input-wrapper > input').on('click', (e) => dp.datepicker("show"));

// On date change
const y  = document.getElementById('year');
const m  = document.getElementById('month');
const d  = document.getElementById('day');

y.value = defaultDate.getFullYear();
d.value = defaultDate.getDate();
m.value = defaultDate.getMonth() + 1;

dp.on('changeDate',function(ev){
    const date = dp.datepicker('getDate');
    console.log(dp.datepicker('getFormattedDate'));
    y.value = date.getFullYear();
    d.value = date.getDate();
    dp.datepicker('hide');
    m.value = date.getMonth() + 1;
})

dp.on('hide',function(ev){
    const date = dp.datepicker('getDate');
    m.value = date.getMonth() + 1;
})
```

```css
label {
      color: #808694;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      line-height: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
}


    
input {
      margin-right: 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: #F4F5F8;
      width: 50px;
}

.span-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
      }
      
span {
        
        color: #808694;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 16px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50px;
}

.main-content {
  min-height: 10vh;
}

.call-form-item-date {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="main-content">
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
</div>

<div class="contacts-call-form">
    <form class="js-form" action="{{ route('send-comment') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item-date">
                <label for="date">Select a date *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <div id="datepickerContainer"></div>
                    <input class="js-form-month" id="month" type="text" name="month">
                    <input class="js-form-day" id="day" type="text" name="day">
                    <input class="js-form-year" id="year" type="text" name="year">
                    <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" style="display: none">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="span-wrapper">
          <span for="month">Month</span>
          <span for="day">Day</span>
          <span for="year">Year</span>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but for some reason the format does not change anyway

Comment: an idea can be `dp.datepicker('getDate')`vs `dp.datepicker('getFormattedDate')` the first one give the complete date string instead of second one that give the formatted date

Comment: I did not understand how exactly to use `getFormattedDate` to display the desired values

Comment: it's the data you want to recover from datepicker, for sample after an event dateChange you can recover the date as a date object with dp.datepicker('getDate') in that case you can manipulate as a js Date – 
or you can also recover it as a formated string with method dp.datepicker('getFormattedDate') in that case the data recovered will be correctly formated with the format pass in parameter of date picker and if you want to display it where you want (with innerText for sample)